# Orientdb perform sum of match statement

Tags: sql, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am using a match statement to retrieve some information in OrientDB the match clause look like this:

```
MATCH 
  {class:Parlamentar, as:p} -RealizaTransacao-> {class:Transacao, as:t} 
       -FornecidaPor-> {class:EmpresaFornecedora, as:e},
  {as:e} -RealizaTransacao-> {class:Transacao, as:t2} -FornecidaPara-> 
{as:p}
RETURN t.VlrDocumento
```

This clause returns the documents value and I need to sum these values. I've tried to do using sub-query like this:

```
select sum(t_VlrDocumento) from (MATCH 
  {class:Parlamentar, as:p} -RealizaTransacao-> {class:Transacao, as:t} 
       -FornecidaPor-> {class:EmpresaFornecedora, as:e},
  {as:e} -RealizaTransacao-> {class:Transacao, as:t2} -FornecidaPara-> 
{as:p}
RETURN t.VlrDocumento)
```

And I've also tried to do like this:

```
select sum(t.VlrDocumento) from (MATCH 
  {class:Parlamentar, as:p} -RealizaTransacao-> {class:Transacao, as:t} 
       -FornecidaPor-> {class:EmpresaFornecedora, as:e},
  {as:e} -RealizaTransacao-> {class:Transacao, as:t2} -FornecidaPara-> 
{as:p}
RETURN t)
```

But none of those worked. Does anybody have a tip to perform a sum of elements from a match statement in OrientDB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both are supposed to work... perhaps there is something peculiar in your data, can you provide a script to create a sample dataset?

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, here is the github link for the ETL that I've used to upload the data: https://github.com/gabrielmm1234/CEAP-ETL . And here is a link to the data that I've used: http://www2.camara.leg.br/transparencia/cota-para-exercicio-da-atividade-parlamentar/dados-abertos-cota-parlamentar . I have used the 2017 csv file.